# Cannot get Metadata Extractor to run

Tags: c#, metadata-extractor

This is probably an embarrassing question (sorry!):  I just installed Metadata Extractor via NuGet without any problem.  However, in

```
    using MetadataExtractor;    

     ...

    Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(file);
```

VisualStudio (2015) tells me that the type or namespace for Metadata cannot be found and that ImageMetadataReader does not contain a definition for readMetadata.  Thought these were all defined within the Metadata Extractor class.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you based your code on the Java sample on the website.  [Check out the C# one instead.](https://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/)

Function names are case sensitive. `readMetadata` does not exist.

Carefully check the return value of `ImageMetadataReader.ReadMetadata()` and I think you will see the issue.  If you mouse over it in Visual Studio, it should show you that it returns an `IReadOnlyList<MetadataExtractor.Directory>` object.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  The code came from a code example I found here on StackExchange, I think. Must have been an outdated one.